# Firefox not offered as default mail application

Tags: firefox, email, default-programs

I'm in the process of switching from Chrome to Firefox. When I go to Default Applications, both are listed under Web, but only Chrome is listed under Mail - no Firefox. So "mailto:" links open Chrome. I thought maybe I should extend /usr/share/applications/firefox.desktop but the value of "Categories" there already includes everything that google-chrome.desktop has. Running Ubuntu 20.04.2 and Gnome. Suggestions welcome - thanks.

Comment: I am not aware that Firefox has any kind of mail client in it. Chrome does. If you do not want Chrome to capture the mail to install a mail client and make it the default.

Comment: @David Are you sure Chrome has a mail client? I can't find any (although I use Chrome only in Windows, in Ubuntu I have Firefox and Chromium). I am pretty sure that Chrome is just a browser, like Firefox.

Comment: Chrome calls the api for gmail when its used.

Comment: This info from the chrome web site might help. Open Chrome settings. Select "Show advanced settings" and click on "Content settings" under "Privacy." Scroll down to "Handlers" and select "Manage handlers." Select "mail.google.com" as your mailto site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mail client by Mozilla is called Thunderbird, Firefox itself is only a browser.

So if you want a Firefox-ish experience, just use Thunderbird.

Comment: Ah OK - thanks for the clarification. This does seem like a hole that Mozilla should plug though. I use gmail like half the world's population, and when I click on a "mailto:" link in Chrome, it opens a gmail "New message" popup in Chrome. From Firefox, this works when the "mailto:" is in a gmail message, not from any other page. Starting up Thunderbird every time is a bit clunky - I might as well have Chrome come up after all, at least it's the same interface! Except now I find that having switched to Thunderbird to try it out, Chrome is no longer offered as a mail application :-(.

Answer (score 3):

Open Firefox and set **Settings** > **General** > **Applications** > **mailto** to **Use Gmail** for example.

Then edit `~/.config/mimeapps.list` and add or replace the following line in the `[Default Applications]` section.

```
x-scheme-handler/mailto=firefox.desktop
```

Answer (score 1):

`xdg-mime default firefox.desktop x-scheme-handler/mailto`

running this command is the same as editing the config file `~/.config/mimeapps.list` mentioned by Igor

P.S. On Debian you might need to use `firefox-esr.desktop` instead of `firefox.desktop`